# Pacman Package manager in LFS

Tags: linux, package-management, pacman, lfs

I'm trying to install a Linux From Scratch system. I know LFS doesn't come with a package manager, but I want to use pacman as my package manager. I googled about it and found some links but they are [old](http://www.vachaev.net/osp/lfsbs.html), and some of the links in them are even `404`. Can someone explain how I can get pacman to work with LFS?
Thank You.

Comment: Could you add that "really old" links into the question? Also if something is 404 it's very likely that it was archived on archive.org

Comment: @pbm add the link. The link for the patch for libtar is 404. Also what is he trying to say I don't get it. :p

Comment: You should probably build [pacman](https://projects.archlinux.org/users/allan/pacman.git/) from the git source.

Comment: Will it work? I mean the link asks to make PKGBUILD and stuff.

Comment: What specifically don't you understand in that page ? PKGBUILD are still used by pacman/makepkg and there is documentation in the [ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD). Some conventions may have changed, but you can check with the current documentation (and ask here if you can't find something).

Comment: ok so pacman doesn't just require pacman itself, it also requires fakeroot and couple of others applications, so i guess i'll have to build them as well.